# C function variable argument length

Tags: c

I want to pass variable argument to a function but don't want set the number in argument. so I check the end of argument with 0 as below:

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void foo(char* str, ... )
{
    printf("str: %s\n",str);
    va_list arguments;                     
    va_start(arguments,str);
    while(1) {
        double data = va_arg(arguments,double); 
        if (data == 0) {
            break;
        }
        printf("data: %.2f\n",data);
    }
    va_end (arguments);
    return;
}

int main()
{
    foo("hello", 5.5, 4.5, 3.5);
}
```

But it seems the out put not correct:

```
str: hello
data: 5.50
data: 4.50
data: 3.50
data: 34498135662005122837381407988349324615424289861359674446209831441373336786008345008385190019649501215393603210517859097842586295826918562939434091794406737728862534747430060032.00
```

The last data output is random value, it should not there!

Comment: I don't see any problems with this on Windows with VS2012. you need to provide more details

Comment: You forget to send 0 as last parameter in the function call `foo("hello", ..., 0);`

Comment: @Sarang So windows is better than MacOSX. I am using MacOSX and output as above. :-)

Comment: No it is not You  are just  lucky

Comment: agreed- you are lucky that it failed and now it got fixed the right way :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could solve it by adding a sentinel value to the values passed.

```
int main()
{
    foo("hello", 5.5, 4.5, 3.5, 0.0);
}
```

This had to be `0.0` in my test, not `0`.

Comment: But, `0.0` is ok if it's not a result of a calculation.

Comment: @iharob, in subsequent tests passing a `double` var of value `0.0`, an `int` var of value `0`, and a plain `0` all worked, so I don't know what the original issue was when passing `0` failed. I only guess that the compiler pushed an `int` instead of a `double` as the function `foo()` does not declare types, but subsequently that was a benign bug..

Comment: Yes it should be `0.0`, since the function will expect a double, not an int.

Answer (score 3):

When you call the function, you don't provide a `0.0` argument. The function tries to print everything up to a zero argument, but there is not such argument.

The function will go on to look at memory where it would expect a 5th, 6th, ... parameter until one such location randomly contains a zero or the program crashes.